# Showing a label right below navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How do I show a label (or any UIView) right below navigation bar in a UIViewController.

I used the following code:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!, 200, 21))
```

However, using `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!` is not sufficient. Using this y co-ordinate keeps label invisible.

What should I use for y co-ordinate to show a UIView right below navigation bar.

Comment: You should try with `y = 65`

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!, 200, 21))

y = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
```

after set y value.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the status bar height which can be found using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

so it should be

```
UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, ((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height), 200, 21))
```